# Why is it said the property doesn't work? Using CommunityToolkit.MVVM

Tags: c#, windows-community-toolkit

I have a view model and a property is annotated as ObservableProperty attribute.

Then, I have a method that set the property, but it is underlined with a red like and I get enrror that says the property doesn't exists.

However, if I use the field, it is underlined with a green line that tells that how I am using ObservableProperty, I should to use the property instead of the field.

In fact, the project compile and I can run the application with no problems, but it is a bit annoyed to have many error that really aren't.

My code is this:

```
[ObservableProperty]
_myVariable;

public void MyMethod()
{
   MyVariable = 1;
}
```

How could i solve this problem?

Thanks.

EDIT: this is an example to can reproduce the problem. This is a view model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;

namespace MvvmCommunityToolkit
{
    public partial class ViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        public int? _dummy;


        [ObservableProperty]
        public int? _dummy2;


        private void MyMethod()
        {
            Dummy = 0;
            Dummy2 = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

At first, i don't have errors. To can reproduce this error, I follow this steps:

- comment _dummy an its attribute. Here, in the method MyMethod(), both, Dummy and Dummy2 are underlined with red line.
- I uncomment _dummy and its attribute. Still Dummy and Dummy2 in the method is marked as error.
- I rebuild. It is succedded, but in the method, still Dummy and Dummy2 are marked as error.
- I comment _dummy and _dummy2 and its properties. Still in the method, Dummy and Dummy2 are marked as error.
- I rebuild. The build fails. It is the expected.
- I uncomment _dummy and _dummy2 and its attributes. Then in the method Dummy and Dummy2 now is correct, no marked as error.

Comment: Please show more code, this isn't sufficient to see what may be wrong. Are you inheriting from `ObservableObject`? Also, that code wouldn't compile as-is, because your property doesn't have a type.

Comment: Also do not prefix the property with an underscore when using MVVM community toolkit.  The code generator in the toolkit will do this automatically when writing the backing field.

Comment: @RyanThomas That's not correct. Both notations are supported, with and without underscore. The Source Generators also don't write the backing fields. A partial class is generated that completes the code, it only adds the property, but the backing field remains the way it is, the name is not changed.

Comment: I have add a code example and the steps to reproduce it.

Comment: Sounds like it works in general, but has hiccups at times. Maybe the Source Generators don't run correctly upon saving the code files. Have you already tried closing the solution, deleting the *bin* and *obj* folders and then opening the solution again?

Comment: Yes, I have realized that when I comment the fields, the error window tells that it is needed to close an open again the solution to can delete this fields. So I have tried to don't comment the fields, close and reopen the solution and it seems it works. It is a bit annoying, but at least it is a solution, better than see many false errors.